# Как добавить большое количество маркеров на картах Google maps в android?

Tags: android, google-maps, карты

Может у кого-то была схожая задача или есть идеи, как сделать? Поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения Вашей задачи рекомендую использовать вот это: [Google Maps Android API utility library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

а именно **Marker clustering** - это позволяет объединять маркеры в кластеры, тем самым уменьшает нагрузку на девайс.

Answer (score 0):

Я у себя так реализовывал:

```
private void setupMarkers() {
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        List<Shop> shops = DBManager.getAllShops(self);
        for (Shop shop: shops){
            options.position(new LatLng(shop.getLatitude(), shop.getLongitude()));
            options.title(shop.getName());
            options.snippet(shop.getAddress());
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
        }
```

Это самый простой вариант. Под свои объекты только переделать придется.